# Why do I not need to use Input.Length[i]?

Tags: if-statement, string-length

```
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int letterCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int specialChar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if ((input[i] >= 'a'&& input[i] <= 'z' )|| (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                letterCount++;
            }
            else if (input[i] >='0'&&input[i]<='9')
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                specialChar++;
            }
        }
```

(input[i] >= 'a'&& input[i] <= 'z' )|| (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z') this is whats bugging me. Shouldn't I have to write input.Length[i] how does the program know that I am still using the input length ?

---

Comment: Also if possible could any one explain the (input[i] >= 'a'&& input[i] <= 'z' ) part ? as I am not sure how the program just goes threw all the letters with this line of code

Answer (score 0):

Your limitations defined in this loop, "i" will go from 0 to the length-1.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length-1; i++)
```

each time you enter the loop you will take input[0], input[1] and so on, that way you will iterate over all the input

Also Input.Length[i] in not valid.

1. Input.Length will return length
2. Input[I] will return the value in place "i" in the input.

Comment: I see, thanks. If possible could you also explain the (input[i] >= 'a'&& input[i] <= 'z' )  part ? I realize it goes through all of the alphabet but not exactly sure how this works.

Comment: The char is converted to his ascii value, also ‘a’ and ‘z’ and it become simple “if in range” compare